# Sharepoint 2010 workflows created in Visual studio deployment and redeployment strategies?

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-activity

We need help from experts regarding workflows deployment strategies.

We have several state machine workflows created using VS-2010, now after deployment, Client will ask for changes inside it e.g. adding activities e.t.c  how do we re-deploy it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research and analysis i posted a [blog post](http://sharepoint497.blogspot.com/2012/09/upgrading-or-redeploying-sharepoint.html), it contains all information related to re-deployment or upgrading visual studio created workflows in SharePoint 2010, i hope this post will save some time of dev's looking for similar information.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

- Update the `AssemblyVersion` in `References.cs`
- Update the version number in `CodeBesideAssembly` in workflow.xml
- Make the changes to the workflow
- Deploy

But the big question is then how do you want running instances of the workflow to behave and hopefully you thought about this before you deployed the first version. For more information about your options see [Versioning a Visual Studio SharePoint Workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2010/04/14/versioning-a-visual-studio-sharepoint-workflow.aspx)